# How to remove rows that have all NaN values for a specific value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df`:

```
         CODE    MONTH_DAY TMAX_x
0        113250   01-01    nan
1        113250   01-02    nan
2        113250   01-03    nan
3        113250   01-04    nan
4        113250   01-05    nan
        ...     ...     ...
16975  47E94706   12-27    22.4
16976  47E94706   12-28    21.1
16977  47E94706   12-29    23.2
16978  47E94706   12-30    24.9
16979  47E94706   12-31    24.4

[16980 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to remove rows that have a specific code value in `CODE` column, only if ALL of their `TMAX_x` values are nan.

For example: If ALL rows that have `CODE` equal to 133250 have only nan values in `TMAX_x` i must remove that rows. (There must be all values nan in `TMAX_x` column for a specific `CODE` value, if at least 1 value are different to nan in `TMAX_x` i must not remove any row).

Expected result:

```
         CODE    MONTH_DAY TMAX_x
        ...     ...     ...
16975  47E94706   12-27    22.4
16976  47E94706   12-28    21.1
16977  47E94706   12-29    23.2
16978  47E94706   12-30    24.9
16979  47E94706   12-31    24.4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` followed by `filter` to keep groups that have at least one non-null value in TMAX_x column:

```
df.groupby('CODE').filter(lambda gp: gp.TMAX_x.notna().any())
```